# field value can't display in null condition in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have problem when i'm using a condition for checking null values in report. My condition is

```
$F{BILANGAN4}==0 ? "-" : ""
```

The values of field does not appear but it just appear "-".

Anyone know about this?

Comment: Checking for null values or 0 ?

Comment: @gopinagh my values is 0

Comment: @AminSCO What is a type of *$F{BILANGAN4}*?

Comment: my $F{BILANGAN4} type is java.lang.long

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `$F{BILANGAN4}==0 ? "-" : ""` will compile-down to. Have you looked at the generated .java code for your report? `java.lang.Long` *could* be null, so you want to check like this:

```
( ( null == $F{BILANGAN4} || $F{BILANGAN4} == 0 ) ? "-" : "" )
```

I usually explicitly add `.longValue()` to calls like that just to be explicit: I'll get a compiler failure if the type isn't correct and I know I need to adjust something and maybe re-consider the code.

Note that the above code (as a text-field value for instance) will only display "-" or nothing. If you want the value of the `$F` to actually display, you'll have to put it in there. I'm fairly sure this is actually what you want:

```
( ( null == $F{BILANGAN4} || $F{BILANGAN4} == 0 ) ? "-" : $F{BILANGAN4} )
```